# Getting started: What kind of thing can we do with the SE-API that we can't do with the SE Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, api, getting-started, data-explorer

I want to know if my slender grasp of the latter will help me learn about the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get meta data about a site as well as about all sites and users within the Stack Exchange sites network, see e.g. the following [routes](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help):

**Api Routes**

- [/stats](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/help/method?method=stats)

  - Gets various system statistics.

**StackAuth Routes**

- [/sites](http://stackauth.com/0.9/help/method?method=sites)

  - Returns a list of all the sites in the StackExchange network
- [/users/{id}/associated](http://stackauth.com/0.9/help/method?method=users/%7Bid%7D/associated)

  - Gets all the associated user accounts across the StackExchange network as identified by the given association_id.

This kind of meta and cross site information is not available via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

You can fetch live data for one. The data explorer uses data that is up to a month old.

Answer (score 1):

Another feature only available is the `/user` `timed_penalty_date` which is the time when a user leaves the penalty box.